# willTransitionTo of DefaultRoute comes into action even though it's not supposed to

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

Let's assume that I'm using the following structure for routes :

```
var React = require('react');
var Router = require('react-router');
var Route = Router.Route;
var DefaultRoute = Router.DefaultRoute;
var App = require('../components/App'),
    About = require('../components/About'),
    Home = require('../components/Home');
var routes = (
    <Route name="app" path="/" handler={App}>
        <Route path="about" name="about" handler={About} />
        <DefaultRoute name="home" handler={Home} />
    </Route>
);

module.exports = routes;
```

And `home` component looks like this :

```
var React = require('react');
var loginStore = require('../stores/LoginStore');
var Home = React.createClass({

displayName: 'Home',

propTypes: {},

statics: {
    willTransitionTo(transition) {
       console.log('HEREEEEEEEE');
        if (!loginStore.isLoggedIn()) {
            loginStore.setTransitionPath(transition.path);
            transition.redirect('login');
        }
    }
},
render: function() {
    return (<div>
    </div>);
}
});

module.exports = Home;
```

Let's assume that the user wants to route to `/about` , although we expect `home` not to come into action , we get the `console.lo`g result in the screen which means `willTransitionTo` of home is running. Is it a bug or I'm missing something ?

Comment: Are your components being exported as modules and then required in your app? or do you have one big file that has all of your components in it?

Comment: @BradBumbalough : Each component is defined as a separate module in a separate file, the same for  `routes`.

Comment: Are you correctly using `module.exports` at the end of the files?

Comment: @BradBumbalough : yes,  just updated the question